# Copying file to server via ssh and the scp command

Tags: bash, ssh, scp

On my home computer, I have a file

```
/Users/Me/Downloads/something.tar.gz
```

which I would like to copy via SSH in

```
/home/me/Matlab
```

on the server of my university.

I have tried to do this by

```
scp /Users/Me/Downloads/something.tar.gz me@hostname:/home/me/Matlab
```

or

```
  scp -r /Users/Me/Downloads/something.tar.gz me@hostname:/home/me/Matlab
```

In both cases, I am asked to fill in my password and after doing this I get the following:

```
/home/me/.private_functions: line 15: bind: warning: line editing not enabled
```

Can you help me, please? I am absolutely new in all these things and already glad that I managed to get ssh at least started.

Kind regards!

**Edit:**

Since the error seems to be in the file .private_functions, here is the content of that file:

[image: screenshot of file private_functions]

Moreover, here is a screenshot when using `scp -v`:

[image: scrrenshot using scp with option -v]

Moreover, I did the same with `scp -vv`, here is the screenshot:

[image: screenshot of using scp with -vv]

**Edit 2:**

Here are screenshots from the out put of command `grep .private_functions ~/.*`

[image]

[image]

Comment: The command line `scp /Users/Me/Downloads/something.tar.gz me@hostname:/home/me/Matlab` is working (for me). Check what do you have in the file `.private_function`. You can enable `scp -v` or even  `ssh -vv` (more than one v) to have more information about what is _really_ happening when you connect to that computer. Good Luck.

Comment: I already tried to open .private_function to have a look at line 15. But unfortunately, I do not know how to open .private_function.

Comment: Did you try with `cat`, `less`, `more`, `nano`, `pico`,`vi`... `:-)` It is only an hidden file (it starts with `.`). I suppose it is on the server. If you are lazy you can do `ssh cat  .private_functions`, if you prefer you can log on the server then read the file... You should understand who (what) is calling that file, It is not a standard one.(for this `ssh -vv` or `scp -v`)

Comment: Ok, I added screenshots. Hope, this may help.

Comment: This _function_ seems that is needed only when you do an interactive login. Instead it is called (probably sourced) even with a non interactive login. It probably needs to be included in the `.bashrc` and probably is instead called/ included in some other start-up file. Search again with `grep .private_functions ~/.*`... __WARNING__ this file includes the present directory (`.`) in your PATH, a security problem usually to avoid.

Comment: How can I include it into .bashrc, i.e. what do I have to write in .bashrc?

Comment: I added screenshots of the output of the grep command.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to replace in your file `.private_functions`:

```
bind "..."
```

by

```
tty=$(tty); [[ $tty != "not a tty" ]] && bind "..."
```

Comment: what does this change do? just curious, have not tested it yet

Comment: This executes your bind command only if you use a terminal.

Comment: by the way. what *is* this bind command resp. what does it do?

Comment: With `bind` you can modify key bindings in your interactive bash. See: `help bind` and section READLINE from `man bash`

Comment: Unfortunately, your suggestion did not make a change. I still get the same warning.

Comment: I updated my answer. I replaced "no tty" by "not a tty".

Comment: Now, when I do the scp command as above, the warning does not appear anymore (the terminal directly gives "Hello, Dennis!" and nothing more). But when I then go into the server (with ssh -i and so on) and go into the directory Matlab, the file has not arrived this directory.

Comment: I deleted the echo "Hello, Dennis!" from .private_functions. Now, it seems to work. Really strange.

Comment: @mathfemi Not so strange if you are connecting via scp you have no terminal where to write Hello... :) BTW all that I see in that file seems to be created for an interactive session. The file is called by .viminfo. Guess what? Now you should see who's calling viminfo. Better to write `grep viminfo .* 2>/dev/null` to redirect the errors to null (the equivalen of a black hole for Linux)... :) enjoy the hunting  :)